# How can I take every channel name from a discord server and then map them into a html selection box? (discord.js v14)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, ejs

Does anyone know how I'm able to take every text channel name from a Discord server and then map them into a html selection box, kind of like how dyno.gg does it on there website.

I have my selection box ready, all I need is to be able to fetch every text channel name and then list them all as a selectable option.

Comment: Expose an endpoint on the back end that returns said channels. Then on the front end, make a GET request to the endpoint to fetch the data and display it.

Comment: Thank you, do you know what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Using ExpressJS would be the easiest path

Comment: Nice, I already have expressjs set up for the website so this should be easy, thank you